# Can't make tooltips work with local css

Tags: html, css, spring, tooltip, bootstrap-4

i'm pretty new with web programming and I encountered this problem when I tried to use bootstrap 4 tooltips (same result with popovers) :

If I include the bootstrap css with this line (linking to the "online" file)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css">
```

the tooltips will work but most of the other styles won't.

If instead I include this other line (linking to local EXACT SAME FILE)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.css">
```

the tooltips won't work but all the other styles will.

These are 2 screenshots of how the login page renders with the 2 different lines

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkCkt.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLy4p.jpg

Obviously the two css are the exact same file.

I'm using Spring Tools Suite, ask if you need more info !

One thing I noticed is that even with the local css (when the tooltip is not displayed) the div is correctly generated into the html code, just not showing up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Bootstrap tooltip is not a css only component. It does require the Bootstrap javascript "stack" to work: [jQuery, Popper.js and bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js). Do you have them loaded?

Comment: Which version if jQuery and Bootstrap js are you using?

Comment: i've got latest versions of bootstrap (4 beta 2) and jquery (3.2.1), actually bootstrap-bundle which includes popper. At the moment i managed to make the tooltips  show but they arent following the data-placement option. To get them to show i only had to switch bootstrap and query-ui load lines ( put bootstrap-bundle first ), looks like there's a conflict between the two and with the ignoreconflict solution none of them works.